# How do I integrate a jQuery script in to my html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.html('');

  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while(index >= 0){
    var msg = streams.home[index];
    var $msg = $('<div></div>');
    $msg.text('@' + msg.userID + ': ' + msg.message);
    $msg.appendTo($body);
    index -= 1;
  }
</script>
```

that I've placed at the bottom of the body of my html file. However, I don't know how to get what the script generates in to my html file. Either I can see the HTML/CSS results or just the script (which generates random lines of lipsum text).

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lipsum.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header> ... </header>
    <div id="main"> 
      // in the webpage, I would like to have the script results
      // display here
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    //see above
  </script>
</body>
```

I've tried moving the script in various places, and adjusting the script's `appendTo()`, but to no avail. How do I do this?

**Update:** Included what I have in the head section. As stated in Max Rocket's comments, lipsum just generates a user ID followed by Lipsum Lorem text. The goal is to emulate a chat room. I have the text, but am trying to get it to display with HTML/CSS content.

Comment: tradiotionally, one uses a script tag in the head to load libraries like jQuery -as you've "hidden" your head, can't say if you are or are not loading jQuery at all

Comment: You've included a script with code that clears the whole page via `$body.html('');`, and now you're unhappy because that works?

Comment: @nnnnnn - I believe the problem is that the script isn't running

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm new to all of this, so I'm not sure how this all works. Please don't assume I'm "unhappy" or complaining about my post. I'm here to ask for help.

Comment: Where is `streams` defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for working solution. 
I assume that your object for streams is similar to what I created there, at least enough so.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var streams = {
        home: [
        {
          userID: "Tom",
          "message": "Lorem ipsum sit alor"
        }, {
          userID: "Dick",
          "message": "Gallia est provincia divese en partes tres"
        }, {
          userID: "Harry",
          "message": "Y tu mama tambien"
        }
       ]
      }

      var index = streams.home.length - 1;

      while (index >= 0) {
        var msg = streams.home[index];
        var $msg = $('<div></div>');
        $msg.text('@' + msg.userID + ': ' + msg.message);
        $msg.appendTo('#main'); // this is where it appends to #main
        index -= 1;
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Chatroom</h1>
  </header>

  <div id="main">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What are you streams? Is this a Twitter feed you're trying to append?

Comment: @MaxRocket It just generates random lines of text (Lorem Lipsum) with fake user names. It's supposed to emulate a "chat room" so to speak. With user ID's and their text. And I'm just trying to get it to display with some HTML/CSS content.

Comment: @MaxRocket I copied and pasted what you have and it's not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103401/discussion-between-alanh-and-maxrocket).

Comment: Revised the answer to include a working snippet model

Answer (score 0):

Your code,

```
var $body = $('body');
    $body.html('');
```

is stripping everything inside your body tag clean. Including any script tags that you have set. So that when you get to your JS code at the bottom of the page it is not there.Your code never fires. You should probably scale down your target for the clearing function.

```
$body.html(''); // This take the body element and clears it.
```

Try a particular inner DOM element like a div or span.